Using the Euler class to show that $\mathbb {CP}^4$ does not embed in $\mathbb R^{12}$
Using the definition of the Euler class I am trying to prove then that $\mathbb {CP}^4$ cannot be embedded in $\mathbb R^{12}$. I know that the are other ways to do this in more generality, but they use advanced technology that I don't have, this is supposed to be doable using only the definition of the Euler class and possible any of the following facts that I have already proven:

For the tautological line bundle $L = L_{\mathbb{CP}^n}$ over $\mathbb{CP}^n$, $a := -c_1(L) \in H^2(\mathbb{CP}^n)$,

$$T(\mathbb{CP}^n) \oplus \mathbb{C} \cong L^* \oplus \cdots \oplus L^* \quad (\text{$n+1$ copies}).$$

The Chern classes of $T(\mathbb{CP}^n)$ and the Pontryagin classes of the real vector bundle are:
$$c(T(\mathbb{CP}^n)) = (1 + a)^{n+1}, \quad p(T(\mathbb{CP}^n)) = (1 + a^2)^{n+1}.$$

Try: I know that for any real oriented vector bundle $E$ over $M$ of rank $ r$, the Euler class is a cohomology class $e(E) \in H^r(M)$. Considering even-dimensional vector bundles to avoid triviality: $r = 2l$
For a real oriented vector bundle $E$, it is related to the Pontryagin class by: $p_l(E) = e(E)^2$.
I also know that the total Pontryagin class of $T(\mathbb{CP}^4)$ is:
$$
p(T(\mathbb{CP}^4)) = (1 + a^2)^5,
$$
where $a = -c_1(L) \in H^2(\mathbb{CP}^4, \mathbb{Z})$. Expanding this, we find, since $a^5=0$:
$$
p(T(\mathbb{CP}^4)) = 1 + 5a^2 + 10a^4 + 10a^6 + 5a^8 + a^{10}=1 + 5a^2 + 10a^4.
$$
Assume that $ \mathbb{CP}^4 $ embeds into $ \mathbb{R}^{12}$. Then the tangent bundle and the normal bundle satisfy:
$$
T(\mathbb{CP}^4) \oplus N \cong \mathbb{R}^{12},
$$
The cohomology ring of $ \mathbb{CP}^4 $ is:
$$
H^*(\mathbb{CP}^4, \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}[a] / (a^5),
$$
where $ a \in H^2(\mathbb{CP}^4, \mathbb{Z}) $. This means:

The highest nonzero cohomology group is $ H^8(\mathbb{CP}^4, \mathbb{Z})$, generated by $a^4$.
Any term of degree higher than $8$, such as $a^6$ or $a^8$, must vanish.

Using the Whitney product formula for Pontryagin classes:
$$
1=p(\mathbb{R}^{12})=p(T(\mathbb{CP}^4)) \cdot p(N) ,
$$
where $ p(\mathbb{R}^{12}) = 1 $ because $ \mathbb{R}^{12} $ is trivial.
Let the total Pontryagin class of $ N $ be: $p(N) = 1 + p_1(N) + p_2(N).$
Substituting $ p(T(\mathbb{CP}^4)) = 1 + 5a^2 + 10a^4  $, we get:
$$
(1 + 5a^2 + 10a^4 ) \cdot (1 + p_1(N) + p_2(N)) = 1.
$$
$$
1 + p_1(N) + p_2(N) + 5a^2 + 5a^2 \cdot p_1(N) + 5a^2 \cdot p_2(N) + 10a^4 + 10a^4 \cdot p_1(N) + 10a^4 \cdot p_2(N) =1
$$
The rank of $ N $ is $r=4$, so its Euler class $ e(N) $ lies in $ H^4(\mathbb{CP}^4, \mathbb{Z}) $, which is generated by $ a^2 $.
so $e(N) = ka^2$ for some integer $k$.
By the relation between Pontryagin classes and the Euler class $p_2(N) = e(N)^2$. Substituting $e(N)$, we get: $p_2(N) = (ka^2)^2 = k^2a^4$, so $p_2(N)$ has degree $8$.
Since $p_1(N)$ has degree $4$ by definition of Pontryagin classes, $p_1(N)=ma^2$.
Equating terms of degree 4
$$
 5a^2 + p_1(N) = 0. \tag{1'} 
$$
Then $m=-5$ and  $p_1(N)=-5a^2$.
Equating terms of degree $8$ and substituting  $p_1(N)=-5a^2$ and $p_2(N)=k^2a^4$:
$$
0 =10a^4 + 5a^2 \cdot p_1(N) + p_2(N) =10a^4 + 5a^2 \cdot (-5a^2) + k^2a^4. \tag{1}
$$
from which $k^2a^4=15a^4$ ie $k^2=15$ since  $a^4$ is a generator of $H^8(\mathbb{CP}^4,\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}$, so it is not $0$.
As sanity check:
Equating terms of degree 12 :
$$
5a^2 \cdot p_2(N)  + 10a^4 \cdot p_1(N)  = 0. \tag{1''}
$$
we get $-35a^6=0$ which is true
Equating terms of degree 16 :
$$
10a^4 \cdot p_2(N)  = 0. \tag{1'''}
$$
we get $150a^8=0$ which is also true
This shows that the Whitney product formula cannot be satisfied under the assumption that $\mathbb{CP}^4 $ embeds into $ \mathbb{R}^{12} $.
Is this a valid proof? Otherwise how would you proceed?

$T(\mathbb{CP}^4)$ is a real bundle of rank $8$, not $4$.

@MichaelAlbanese  I fixed that, would that make this proof correct?

It is not correct. The equality $p_4(T(\mathbb{CP}^4))=e(T(\mathbb{CP}^4))^2$ is true, but not helpful: both classes lie in $H^{16}(\mathbb{CP}^4; \mathbb{Z}) = 0$. It seems like you wanted to use this equality to show that $e(T(\mathbb{CP}^4))$ can't exist, but it does, it's $5a^4$. One major problem is you cannot take the square root of a cohomology class (in general, there are many different cohomology classes with the same square). Note, at no point of your argument are you assuming that $\mathbb{CP}^4$ embeds in $\mathbb{R}^{12}$ - more precisely, you never use the fact that $N$ exists.

@MichaelAlbanese How do you arrive to $e(T(\mathbb{CP}^4))=5a^4$ if it is not using that equality by computing first  $p_4(T(\mathbb{CP}^4)) $?  I added an Edit about the things I know about the Euler class, how would I compute it using $e(E) = \left[\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\right)^l \text{Pfaffian}(E, \nabla)\right] \in H^{2l}(M).$, since it is the only other equality I have? I don't know how to compute that Pfaffian.

There are two ways. First, the top Chern class of a complex vector bundle is equal to its Euler class. Second, for a closed oriented manifold $M$, the Euler class of $TM$ satisfies $\langle e(TM), [M]\rangle = \chi(M)$.

@MichaelAlbanese ... I modified the solution...would it be correct now?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The structure of the proof is now fine, although it can be streamlined a bit. I also have the following comments:

When writing $T(\mathbb{CP}^4)\oplus N \cong \mathbb{R}^{12}$, the first two bundles are bundles over $\mathbb{CP}^4$. I assume you intended $\mathbb{R}^{12}$ to denote the restriction of the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{R}^{12}$ to $\mathbb{CP}^4$. It would be clearer to denote this by $T\mathbb{R}^{12}|_{\mathbb{CP}^4}$. Alternatively, maybe you meant the trivial rank $12$ real bundle over $\mathbb{CP}^4$, which is commonly denoted $\varepsilon^{12}_{\mathbb{CP}^4}$, or simply $\varepsilon^{12}$ if there is no chance of confusion.
You wrote $p(\mathbb{R}^{12}) = p(T(\mathbb{CP}^4))p(N)$ which is true in this case, but not true in general. The general statement is that for oriented vector bundles $E\to B$ and $F \to B$, we have $2p(E\oplus F) = 2p(E)p(F)$. If $H^*(B; \mathbb{Z})$ has no $2$-torsion (e.g. $B = \mathbb{CP}^4$), then this implies $p(E\oplus F) = p(E)p(F)$.
Your sanity checks didn't actually help to confirm your calculations as $(1'')$ and $(1''')$ are true for degree reasons, so they would have held for any choice of $m$ and $k$.
This argument actually shows something stronger: $\mathbb{CP}^4$ does not immerse into $\mathbb{R}^{12}$.


Regarding the first comment, would any interpretation be equally correct in this proof or is there one that is more natural in this context? Secondly, regarding the second comment, maybe a naive question, you are just cancelling a factor 2, why isn't this just a trivial algebraic step? you say I need there is no 2-torsion to do that

I would say $T\mathbb{R}^{12}|_{\mathbb{CP}^4}$ is more natural (although, this is isomorphic to $\varepsilon^{12}$). As for cancelling by two, consider the following example. If $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, does $2x = 2y$ imply $x = y$?

In my lectures notes I just have the property as $p(E\oplus F)= p(E)p(F)$ for oriented vector bundles, without any reference to that 2-torsion property

As far as I know, that is not correct. See Theorem 15.3 of Characteristic Classes by Milnor and Stasheff.
